# Call a method when specific key combination is pressed anywhere in the app, as long as application is currently focused window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My objective is to allow users of my app to bringup what I'm calling my debug console by pressing CTRL + F11 on their keyboard.

Simply put, I need to call a `ToggleDebug();` method, which will enable my debug tracing code and display the window. I'd like for my application to do this at any point when CTRL + F11 is pressed, regardless of where the user currently has focus the cursor as long as my application is the currently focused window.

My app is deployed through Click Once -- so its a partial trust type environment.

In an old VB6 app, I had been using a `wend` loop with call to `DoEvents()` and a windows API call... needless to say, I'm hoping there is a better way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the PreviewKeyDown event of your window.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
}

void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.F11) && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control))
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you recomending PreviewKeyDown vs KeyDown?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown on the window will surely get hit every time.  KeyDown does not.  For instance, if a control in your window internally handles KeyDown events and sets its e.Handled to True, that event will not get raised on the Window.